# iPhone forgets how to bluetooth, audio app overnight

Tags: iphone, audio, bluetooth

Overnight, my iPhone forgets how to Bluetooth.  It also forgets which audio app I was using.

Let's start at 7:30AM when I get in my car, assume everything is working, and go from there.

1. I turn on my car, Bluetooth connects automatically ("device is connected")
2. I push the play button on the Bluetooth adapter and a podcast starts playing (with my phone in my pocket).
3. I get in my car at lunch, everything works as above
4. I get in my car to go home, everything works as above
5. I get home, do whatever in the evening, go to sleep
6. Next morning, I get in my car, turn it on
7. Bluetooth does not connect automatically.
8. I need to open the Bluetooth settings and manually select the device.
9. Sometimes this doesn't work and I need to turn off/on Bluetooth for it to connect.  This doesn't seem to be the fault of the Bluetooth adapter.  It will patiently wait for the iPhone to figure out what's going on.
10. Once connected, I click the play button on the adapter.
11. Either nothing happens, or some random song from my local iTunes collection starts playing.  Overnight, the audio system has forgotten the last audio app.  This is the same for controlling audio from the lock screen or the control panel.
12. I open my podcast app and click play directly.
13. GOTO 3

So I guess there are two issues here:

1. Why does the iPhone completely forget what audio app I was using yesterday?
2. Why does Bluetooth stop working overnight?

Other info:

1. I don't have any other Bluetooth devices registered with my phone.
2. I charge my phone overnight, but don't usually turn it off
3. I use it pretty much every evening as a control device for a Sonos speaker.
4. iPhone 5S, iOS 8.3 (although this has happened in older versions of iOS)
5. My usual podcast app is Pocketcasts, but my problem applies to all audio apps, not just Pocketcasts and not just podcast apps.
6. I have the Himbox Bluetooth adapter, as recommended by thewirecutter.

What I expect:
When I get in my car, Bluetooth should connect automatically and when I push play, it should continue playing whatever I was listening to yesterday.  This seems like a reasonable expectation.

Comment: What happens if you just turn Bluetooth off and back on in the car? Will it connect then?   How does it connect to the Sonos if not by Bluetooth?

Comment: The Bluetooth adapter is off when the car is off and turns on when the car is started.  Sonos does not support Bluetooth.  It has its own proprietary mesh network, which in practice is indistinguishable from wifi.

Comment: I meant just turn the phones bluetooth on and off?  without re-pairing.  Specifically what I had in mind was flipping up the Control Center and clicking the bluetooth icon off, then back on.  Does that make it connect?